# pytest with classes python

Tags: class, pytest, self

I wrote the following code : 
publisher.py:

```
import six
from google.api_core.exceptions import AlreadyExists
from google.cloud.pubsub import types

class publisher(object):
    """Publisher Object which has the following attributes
      Attributes:
          pubsub: publisher client
          project_name: Name of project
          topic_name: Name of topic
    """

    def __init__(self, pubsub, project_name, topic_name, batch_settings=(), *args, **kwargs):
        self.pubsub = pubsub
        self.project_name = project_name
        self.topic_name = topic_name
        self.batch_settings = types.BatchSettings(
            *batch_settings)  # Batch setting Pub/Sub accepts a maximum of 1,000 messages in a batch,
        # and the size of a batch can not exceed 10 megabytes

    def _full_project_name(self):
        """Returns Fully Qualified Name of project"""
        return self.pubsub.project_path(self.project_name)
```

and I wrote 3 test unfortunately the third one has been failing. 
Below is the code I wrote for tests:

test_publisher.py:

```
from google.cloud import pubsub
import pytest
from publisher import publisher

PROJECT = 'ProjectTest'
TOPIC_NAME = 'TopicTest'

@pytest.fixture
def pubsub():
    yield pubsub.PublisherClient()


def test_init_value():
    sample_publisher=publisher(pubsub,PROJECT,TOPIC_NAME,())
    assert sample_publisher.project_name == 'ProjectTest'
    assert sample_publisher.topic_name == 'TopicTest'
    assert sample_publisher.pubsub == pubsub
    assert sample_publisher.batch_settings.max_messages == 1000
    assert sample_publisher.batch_settings.max_bytes == 10 * (2 ** 20)
    assert sample_publisher.batch_settings.max_latency == 0.05

def test_init_with_no_values():
    with pytest.raises(Exception) as e_info:
        sample_bad_init = publisher()

def test_full_project_name ():
    sample_publisher = publisher(pubsub, PROJECT, TOPIC_NAME, ())

    assert sample_publisher._full_project_name() == 'projects/ProjectTest'
```

I am currently getting the following error, which I can't understand, unfortunately:

```
 line 26, in _full_project_name
    return self.pubsub.project_path(self.project_name)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'project_path'
```

Any help with this, please. 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of fixture should be changed.

```
@pytest.fixture
def google_pubsub():
    yield pubsub.PublisherClient()
```

You should add google_pubsub as argument to test test_full_project_name(google_pubsub) and test_init_value(google_pubsub).

In Test test_init_value you use module pubsub imported from from google.cloud import pubsub, what is wrong.
Test test_init_value passes because you comparing module(pubsub) in line

```
assert sample_publisher.pubsub == google_pubsub
```